# delete postgresql server from mac

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I installed postgresql server on mac with `brew install postgres` because I want to practice it but it seems I installed the wrong thing? What I need is to run the installer from the official website ?

I cannot find how to uninstall the postgresql server

Comment: How did you try to uninstall it? with command line? did you try 'brew uninstall postgresql'

Comment: Brew is fine and you installed the right package. See [wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew). You can `brew uninstall postgres` to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have installed was correct. But if you want to install .dmg package of postgres then you can do that as well.

First, uninstall the current version of Postgres by using

`brew uninstall postgres`

and then Navigate to the following below URL to get your desire Postgres .dmg package
[offical Postgres .dmg for mac](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)

Disclosure: I work for EnterpriseDB (EDB), we create and certify the Mac installers for all supported PostgreSQL versions.